# Browser resize add event width min-max with Js / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

```js
/*Add Click show To Menu*/
    (function ($) {
     $.fn.openActive = function (activeSel) {
      activeSel = activeSel || ".active";
      var c = this.attr("class");
      this.find(activeSel).each(function () {
       var el = $(this).parent();
       while (el.attr("class") !== c) {
        if (el.prop("tagName") === 'UL') {
         el.show();
        } else if (el.prop("tagName") === 'LI') {
         el.removeClass('tree-closed');
         el.addClass("tree-opened");
        }
        el = el.parent();
       }
      });
      return this;
     }
     $.fn.treemenu = function (options) {
      options = options || {};
      options.delay = options.delay || 0;
      options.openActive = options.openActive || false;
      options.activeSelector = options.activeSelector || "";
      this.find("> li").each(function () {
       e = $(this);
       var subtree = e.find('> ul');
       var toggler = $('<span>');
       toggler.addClass('toggler');
       e.prepend(toggler);
       if (subtree.length > 0) {
        subtree.hide();
        e.addClass('tree-closed');
        e.find(toggler).click(function () {
         var li = $(this).parent('li');
         li.find('> ul').toggle(options.delay);
         li.toggleClass('tree-opened');
         li.toggleClass('tree-closed');
        });
        $(this).find('> ul').treemenu(options);
       } else {
        $(this).addClass('tree-empty');
       }
      });
      if (options.openActive) {
       this.openActive(options.activeSelector);
      }
      return this;
     }
    })(jQuery);




    function viewport() {
        var e = window, a = 'inner';
        if (!('innerWidth' in window )) {
            a = 'client';
            e = document.documentElement || document.body;
        }
        return { width : e[ a+'Width' ] , height : e[ a+'Height' ] };

    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

         var dcwidth=$(window).width();
         if(dcwidth <= 1024) {
             $("#nav_menu ul.menu").treemenu({}).openActive();
         }   
    });
```

I have Add click show to menu width treemenu jQuery.

My jQuery working on > 1024px and add Active treemenu on <= 102px.

But when my Browser > 1024px i resize to <= 1024px my jQuery not add event Active treemenu. How to resize Browser  to <= 1024px add Active treemenu and resize to > 1024px clear Active treemenu.

Thanks!